# ¿Por qué dejaron de usarse las contracciones "dél", "della" y "dello"? ¿Cuándo cayeron en desuso?

Tags: historia, contracciones

Parece ser que las únicas contracciones que han llegado al español actual son [*al*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=1PTvt8b) y [*del*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C5sAXFD). Sin embargo, en tiempos se usaron en español muchas otras. Algunas eran contracciones por motivos únicamente de ahorro de espacio, como el uso de una [virgulilla](https://dle.rae.es/?id=btCZ7EZ) sobre las vocales (para representar un sonido *n* omitido) o sobre la *q* (para representar *que*):

[image: Covarrubias]

Estas contracciones no modificaban la pronunciación de la palabra original, pero otras sí lo hacían. Es el caso de *dél*, *della* y *dello*:

[image: Della]

Estas contracciones entiendo que sí modificaban la palabra original, al igual que *al* y *del* no se pronuncian *a el* ni *de el*. Lo que no entiendo es como, al contrario que las mencionadas, estas contracciones se perdieron, dado que supuestamente agilizan el habla. Lo curioso es que hoy día aún se encuentran en el diccionario:

> **[dél](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C5wxfgH)**
>
> 1. contracc. desus. De él.

> **[dello, lla](https://dle.rae.es/?id=C84Jape)**
>
> 1. contracc. desus. De ello.

Obviamente están marcadas como en desuso, puesto que de hecho hoy día nadie dice "della" sino "de ella". Bueno, tal vez en algunas regiones de habla rápida lo sigamos pronunciando a la antigua...

El caso es: ¿por qué estas contracciones dejaron de usarse en la expresión escrita? ¿Cuál fue el motivo de su caída en desuso? ¿Cuándo ocurrió esto?

---

Otras contracciones en desuso que siguen apareciendo en el diccionario, algunas de las cuales podrían aplicar también a la pregunta aunque parecen más rebuscadas: [*destotro*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DUfL0gt), [*dí*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DcrvxSh), [*dentrambos*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=CDrELJl), [*desdel*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Cn4tCrB), [*deste*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=DSn3h29), [*na*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=QAiBQ5D), [*doy*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=EAsKyVN), [*dese*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Cndk8US), [*dallá*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BpngtL7).

Comment: Para ver si la pregunta era duplicada busqué "della" en el sitio y me salieron algunos posts pero no el que respondía a mi pregunta, no se me ocurrió buscar "dello". ^__^U